# Javascript: get object from checkbox

Tags: javascript, jsp

Suppose there is a model class called "Device" which contains many relevant attributes, is there any way to get the "Device" object in the checkbox by using Javascript ?

If I didn't elaborate clearly, here is the sample:

JSP page:

```
<c:forEach var="device" items="${row.deviceList}">
    <input type="checkbox" name="deviceDetails" value="${device}">
    <c:out value="${device.equipNo}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Javascript:

```
var total = document.getElementsByName("deviceDetails");
// run through all element of checkedbox named deviceDetails
for(j=0; j<total.length; j++)
{
  <!-- get instance Device object ? -->
  alert(total[j].value);
}
```

I have tried to call total[j].value which only returned me the string of toString() function instead of the "Device" object.

The purpose for me to do this way is because if I can't get the entire "Device" object, I need to get every attribute one by one through checkbox and assemble them as "Device" object in Javascript. Such as:

JSP page:

```
<c:forEach var="device" items="${row.deviceList}">
    <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="${device.stnID}">
    <c:out value="${device.stnID}" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="stnName" value="${device.stnName}">
    <c:out value="${device.stnName}" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="equipNo" value="${device.equipNo}">
    <c:out value="${device.equipNo}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Javascript:

```
var allID = document.getElementsByName("id");
var allName = document.getElementsByName("stnName");
var allNo = document.getElementsByName("equipNo");

var deviceList = new Array(); 
var device = new Object();

for(i=0; i<allID.length; i++)
{
    device.id = allID[i].value; 
    device.stnName = allName[i].value; 
    device.equipNo = allNo[i].value;

     deviceList.push(device);
}
```

Personally, I don't think the second approach is a good idea. Hence, hope someone here can give better suggestions or any idea to solve pass by object in the checkbox. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass `Java Objects` to be interpreted by Javascript like you did. You need convert your object for a notation that is understandable by both languages, Java and JS. A way I use to do this is convert my java object to JSON, and get it by the client side with javascript.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jefferson. I managed to complete using JSON, I found out it really useful to communicate between front-end JSP and back-end servlet. By the way, I used default JSON2.js for the front-end JSP and Gson for the back-end Java Servlet. They work great!